# TeamCity Email Notifier Error SMTP Port Reset

Tags: smtp, teamcity

We have recently set up email notifications, and are having some issues.

When adding the SMTP config, the test emails are received with no issue. However when a build is run there will be no email sent, and the notification logs will contain an entry like so

```
error: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: mail.****.com, 25; timeout 60000;
```

The server logs won't have an entry for the error.

We have found that setting the port to 0, saving, then setting the port back to 25 will then cause the build notifications to start sending out. We have found that this needs to be done roughly every 24 hours

Any ideas why resetting the port to the same value would cause the emails to start sending? Or ss there any way to programmatically set the values?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved with an update to the latest version (as of November 2019) of both the build server and build agents. The previous build server was running on Version 3.x.x and may have been incompatible